# Behavior of Flash while "dashing"

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that I can extend the range of certain dashes with Flash while the animation is running (e.g. Shen Taunt+Flash, Gragas Bodyslam+Flash).

But is this behavior **consistent through different [types of dashes](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dash)**?

- Auto-targeted
- Direction-targeted
- Ground-targeted
- Unit-targeted

For Example:

- Alistars Headbutt
- Braums Stand Behind Me

So if I "jump" to a target can I use flash to extend the range of the ability or would it simply override the action?

If so, are there certain states of the animation (especially with Alisters Headbutt) I can do this and can I change the direction "mid-air"?

Comment: I don't know the answer offhand without testing, but I suspect that you can only use flash during non-targeted dashes. In the first two examples you mention, the champion will move in any direction (depending on where you point them). The other two examples require a target and only apply their effects when they arrive - flashing would interrupt that, so in order to prevent the skill from being wasted, flash is probably disabled during the dash. (You can, of course, use flash immediately after dashing to a target.)

Comment: @MageXy yeah that would make sense in a way. I didn't thought about the difference between targeted and non-targeted dashes.

Comment: I don't think you can compare within the different dash types. Because they do different things. For instance alistars headbutt and vi's assault and battery. If you flash during alistars headbutt you'll make the enemy move in a different direciton, but with vi (assuming you can even flash which im not sure of) you will be doing exactly the same thing, regardless of the direction you came from.

Answer (score 3):

They way flashes work with abilities is they simply move your champion while the animation is playing out. If you flash during the ability's animation, the animation will complete at your end location from flash. If the ability is direction based, it will use the new direction you are facing at the end of your flash (you can ult flash with cass and lux and change directions of the ulti). If the ability is target based, it will still have the same target afterwards (see tristanna ulti), however, if the ability pushes a unit in a direction away from you, you can change the direction by flashing, as it will use your new position to judge which direction they should be pushed (see ult flash with lee or trist, or vayne condemn). If the ability is area targeted however, such as a ziggs q, it will not extend the range. Flash will also negate the damage dealt by lee's q, as will using his w during the dash.

Comment: You can extend the range, such as gragas' dash (bodyslam?) you flash mid dash. The direction thing is true and widely used, such as lee sin ult or ashe volley. What about alistar's headbutt? If you flash at the last second could you actually headbutt them towards the way you came from?

Comment: @Aequitas I have never tried to headbutt flash. the animation is pretty quick. It is simpler to Pulverize flash into a headbutt the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I last played so people might correct me in the comments.

Last thing I knew is that dashes stops the movement input from an ability. But not the ability itself.

So, for example, if you dash with Shen and you flash right after you did the input for the dash, Shen will "only flash" with a taunt hitbox around him for a few milliseconds. On the opposite end, if you flash at the end of the dash, you will gain distance and still have that taunt hitbox around you.

That's basically how the flash mechanic works for most characters.

In the case of Lee Sin's R-Flash combo, it's just that the cast has still the same target after your flash than before. So if you are still in range of that initial target after the flash, the target will go to the post flash direction instead of the pre-flash. I think the same would apply to other targetting abilities.